# Ember.js asynchronous model

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ember.js, promise

I have a text file that I am using to create a table using the ember-models-table (https://github.com/onechiporenko/ember-models-table) component. I have a function that converts the file into a json object. I am having some difficulty getting asynchronous loading. I want the page with the table headers to load immediately and the data to display once it has been loaded. What I currently have doesn't display anything until the data is loaded. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

function getData(columns, url, deliminator) {
  return Ember.$.get(url).then(function(file) {
    var data = [];
    var headers = [];
    var lines = file.split("\n");

    for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
      headers[i] = columns[i].propertyName;
    }

    for(var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++){
      var obj = {};
      var currentline = lines[j].split(deliminator);

      for(var k = 0; k < headers.length; k++){
        obj[headers[k]] = currentline[k];
      }

      data.push(obj);
    }

    return data;
  });
}

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    var columns = [
      {
        "propertyName": "date",
        "title": "Date/Time"
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "application",
        "title": "Application"
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "priority",
        "title": "Priority"
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "message",
        "title": "Message"
      }
    ];

    var url = 'http://localhost:4200/Errors.log';
    var deliminator = '|';
    return getData(columns, url, deliminator).then(function(data) {
      return {columns, data};
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ember table models will properly update, the trick is to not return the promise, but to return an object immediately and asynchronously update the object after the fact.

#### Populate Data

```
function populateData(columns, url, deliminator, data) {
  Ember.$.get(url).then(function(file) {
    var headers = [];
    var lines = file.split("\n");

    for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
      headers[i] = columns[i].propertyName;
    }

    for(var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++){
      var obj = {};
      var currentline = lines[j].split(deliminator);

      for(var k = 0; k < headers.length; k++){
        obj[headers[k]] = currentline[k];
      }

      // this is important here, you want to use pushObject instead of push
      data.pushObject(obj);
    }
  });
}
```

#### Route

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    var columns = [
      {
        "propertyName": "date",
        "title": "Date/Time"
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "application",
        "title": "Application"
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "priority",
        "title": "Priority"
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "message",
        "title": "Message"
      }
    ];

    var url = 'http://localhost:4200/Errors.log',
        deliminator = '|',
        data = [];
    populateData(columns, url, deliminator, data);

    // ES6 Enhanced Object Properties, Property Shorthand
    return {columns, data};
  }
});
```

#### Slight rework with array replacement

```
function getData(columns, url, deliminator) {
  return Ember.$.get(url).then(function(file) {
    var headers = [];
    var data = [];

    var lines = file.split("\n");

    for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
      headers[i] = columns[i].propertyName;
    }

    for(var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++){
      var obj = {};
      var currentline = lines[j].split(deliminator);

      for(var k = 0; k < headers.length; k++){
        obj[headers[k]] = currentline[k];
      }

      // this is important here, you want to use pushObject instead of push
      data.push(obj);
    }
    return data;
  });
}
```

#### Route

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    var columns = [
      {
        "propertyName": "date",
        "title": "Date/Time"
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "application",
        "title": "Application"
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "priority",
        "title": "Priority"
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "message",
        "title": "Message"
      }
    ];

    var url = 'http://localhost:4200/Errors.log',
        deliminator = '|',
        dataObj = { data: [] };

    getData(columns, url, deliminator).then(data => Ember.set(dataObj, 'data', data));

    // ES6 Enhanced Object Properties, Property Shorthand
    return {columns, dataObj};
  }
});
```

Inside your template you would then reference `{{model.dataObj.data}}` instead of `{{model.data}}`

Comment: So it now loads the page and headers immediately but then hangs and the data never loads. It is making my browser (Chrome) hang and I have to force quit it. Nothing is coming up on the console. Any ideas?

Comment: Wow, that's impressive, if you debug through it, where does it start spinning?

Comment: So it actually works, but so incredibly slow it appears to crash. If the pipe delimited file has 500 rows it takes almost 30 seconds. Any idea why the change decreased the speed by so much? My guess is it has something to do with the `pushObject ` but I don't know what.

Comment: pushObject informs ember that you've added an item to the collection.  If you just use push it won't know that the collection has changed, and won't update any dependent items.  My guess is something with ember models tables is very slow at adding items after the fact.  it's possible that instead of populating the array after the fact, replacing a fully populated array after the fact might be more efficient.  I'll toss up an example

Comment: I am getting the following error when navigating to the route: Error while processing route: dashboard.logs.error Cannot read property 'then' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined          vendor.js:39394 Error: More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: dashboard.logs.error           vendor.js:39394 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: Will you put your implementation in the question

Comment: I made a typo somewhere, I just retried it and it worked perfectly. A little slow with large tables but good enough! I'll make the first row say loading and be done. Thanks!